# How to open LAS files in Google Earth Pro

Tags: qgis, geotiff-tiff, lidar, google-earth, las

I have received LAS files and I would like to extract the GIS data and use it in Google Earth. Is there a way to open LAS files directly in Google Earth Pro, if not what are the steps to do that?

Comment: Not directly, what ETL tools do you have.? you might have better luck with a tool like https://plas.io/ to view point clouds.

Comment: The phrase GIS data is rather broad.  Do you want to create a ground and/or canopy DEM and from that create hillshade, slope and other rasters, and/or contours and streams, and/or canopy height models, etc. ?  If so do that in QGIS then add those to Google Earth as needed.  You can also instead add the Google Earth imagery to your QGIS project.

Answer (score 0):

The answer might be a little late, and in this case, it is interesting to know how did you manage. If not, it would be interesting to know what you intend to do. Indeed, depending on the answer you should go for one solution or another. If the point is Google Earth then, you should use a software to transform the LAS into KML ([link](https://support.google.com/earth/answer/7365595?hl=en&co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop#:%7E:text=On%20your%20computer%2C%20open%20Google,Import%20KML%20file%20from%20Drive.)) or any other native format of Google Earth Pro that you master. Now, if you aim to share access to the data while securing them and do much more, you can also have a look at [ATIS](https://www.atis.cloud/en/)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).